# Error: Multiple annotations found at this line

Tags: xml, eclipse, spring-mvc, eclipse-juno

Every now and then, I am facing the following problem while working on eclipse (JUNO).
Here is the error:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
    - cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
```

Here is a snippet of my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

</beans>
```

Please guide me to identify the problem in xml code, if there any, and how to resolve it.

Thanks.